# Performing multiple setTimeout's in a class

Tags: javascript, class, settimeout

I have a javascript class object that I want to use multiple times on the same page, and it requires a `setTimeout` function to work as it keeps ticking over in the background. However, as you can see in this fiddle, on the timeout call, its only referencing the newest instance of the object. Does anyone know how I can sort it? Preferably, I would like to see how it is done not in jQuery, I like to understand exactly how it does it.

http://jsfiddle.net/cgoddard/yQDLe/20/

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't recommend this: `if (!interval)` — someday you will probably need to use 0 ms interval, and the constructor will set the interval to 1000 ms.

Comment: @Susei: Execute something every zero milliseconds? Hm...

Comment: Nah, don't think i'd ever have to go that far though. The smallest is probably 1000 anyway

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: It may be handy if you need to schedule a coroutine to "as soon as possible", right after the caller function has done its work. For example, in a realtime renderer.

Comment: @Susei: Yes, it may be handy, but not when you're doing that over and over again.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: A realtime renderer I suggested as an example is exactly the case when you do it over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `this.doDelayed` inside a doubly nested function, the `this` keyword doesn't refer to your `test` object. Instead, it refers to whatever object the currently executing function was called for, which is probably `window`.

To overcome this, you have to save your `this` in the very beginning of the `test` function, say like this: `var $this = this;`
Then you can refer to that very object using `$this`.

Besides this, when you write simply `x = something`, the symbol `x` is treated like a property on the `window` object (also known as "global variable"). Therefore, both your `doDelayed` and `construct` functions end up on the `window` object. Consequently, when you do this second time, they both get overwritten. This is why you get same results twice.
Instead, you should write `$this.doDelayed = function() ...` (where `$this` is your saved value of `this` from above), and do similarly for `construct`.

Comment: ah, didn't realise it had to go that far. Well, bombed the thing out with `this.`s and it works perfectly now. Thanks